# Does deleting the tabindex = '-1' attribute also affect web accessibility when the modal window is shown?

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, accessibility, tabindex

Is it an accessibility issue to add the `tabindex = '-1'` attribute only when the modal window is not exposed and to delete the tabindex attribute when the modal window is exposed?
Naturally, I will add the `tabindex = '-1'` property again if the modal window is closed again and not exposed.
I think there's no problem accessing the keyboard tab this way. Is there another problem?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are doing this to prevent people from accessing the modal when it is not active there is nothing wrong with what you are doing. You can safely add and remove the `tabindex` attribute on elements and screen reader software will cope with that just fine.

However I would recommend also adding `aria-hidden="true"` to the modal at the same time.

This is so that screen reader users don't jump to a `h1-h6` (for example) within the modal as screen reader users also navigate by non-focusable elements, using shortcuts in their screen reader software.

Don't forget to toggle it to `aria-hidden="false"` when the modal is active!

In this instance you **are not** safe to delete the attribute, **you must toggle it** between `false` and `true` or you will cause accessibility problems with some screen readers.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply.
Is it the same opinion that using tabindex = '-1' add & delete and aria-hidden's true & false will not affect web accessibility and tab accessibility?

Comment: `aria-hidden="true"` makes sure information within is not accessible to screen readers (think of it as `display: none` for screen readers), your `tabindex="-1"` removes the item (and it's children) from the tab order so stops anyone tabbing to content within it. You can safely remove your `tabindex="-1"` to make an item (and it's children) appear within the tab order again As I said screen reader users do not navigate via the `tab` key normally, they would navigate by headings etc. hence why I said use both.